# External Hard Disk or USB stick , keeps data of previously connected PCs?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, usb-storage

Do External Hard Disks or USB sticks keeps in some table or so, the data to which computer they were connected?

Is it possible from the external HDD or USB stick, retrieve the info (name or something) about the computers they were connected.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hdd and Usb pen drive do not keep by themself information about the computer connected. Usually. (Some special usb devices that seems usb pen drive but that have some computing components inside can do whatever they are programmed for).

But the computers can leave temporary files with information about themselves (but even hidden trash can directories...)

Comment: and what kind of information? Does this temporary info contains user data?

Comment: Just as example a temporary word file can contain information about the word licence, version of OS, of word, user that created it, time of creation and modification,I don't remember if the computer name too...

Comment: Also if they just were connected to a PC for a short time? nothing stored on the HDD, nothing transferred, just connected.

Comment: talking about sensitive data, passwords  or so.... is possible to find this info out?

Comment: @user155293 If nothing was transferred then the answer is clearly no.

Comment: If the computer is set to automatically execute the autorun and there is a malicious autorun it can execute an arbitrary code. If the computer is set to search for the operative system on usb before then on the drive and the usb is plugged in at the boot of the system again it can be executed an arbitrary code. Else not.